# Check content of XML in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, curl

I am unable to wrap my head around this issue and hope for your help.

In a bash script I use a curl command which should get data from a server. The curl response is being put into a bash variable, because I want to check the response.

The response looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body><dp:response xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
    <dp:timestamp>2018-02-28T13:31:36+01:00</dp:timestamp>
    <dp:result> OK </dp:result>
    </dp:response>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

The important part is:

```
<dp:result> OK </dp:result>
```

How can I check within my bash script whether this exact string is in the variable (or not)?
I tried several approaches with different kind of escapes, however, failed miserably so far (always ending up with an issue with one of the special characters).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, using *the proper tool for the right job* :

### Command :

```
curl ..... | xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name()="result"]/text()'
```

or

```
xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name()="result"]/text()' http://domain.tld/path
```

or

```
curl ..... | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//*[local-name()="result"]/text()'
```

### Output:

```
OK
```

### Finally :

```
#!/bin/bash

result="$(chosen_command)"

if [[ $result == *OK* ]]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo >&2 "ERROR"
    exit 1
fi
```

(replace `chosen_command` by... your chosen command)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response...but most of my response is not shown in the questions...due to a ton of special characters. I am trying to fix it....

Comment: You should instead add the more informations possible.

  
Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello Gilles, thank you VERY much. It works! Much appreciated.